# How to delete pods in openshift-restclient-java

Tags: java, openshift

I'm trying to restart and delete a OpenShift pod programmatically. Using openshift-restclient-java. I found out only how to rebuild a deployment config. But need to restart only one pod or delete it

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Trying to learn how to decrease, increase and delete pods by using openshift-restclient-java. I need methods in multi pod application that can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Increase - Create Pods
You can create the pod from the configuration

> https://docs.openshift.com/online/rest_api/api/v1.Pod.html#http-request

Decrease - Delete Pods
Delete the pod with the name/id

> https://docs.openshift.com/online/rest_api/api/v1.Node.html#http-request-8